# how to save to a local server and email a php webform as a pdf

Tags: php, forms, pdf

I work for a company that uses a large amount of web forms on our intranet (based on the apache server)

I need a way to be able to generate a pdf from these web forms, save it to a file on our server, and send a copy to some specified email addresses. Currently the php forms get put into a html email template and sent when the submit button is pressed.

The saved forms need to have a individual file name (eg storename.date.formname.submittedby.pfd) so we can keep a record of the important ones.

Im still a noob for programming, so might need very simple answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear. You say you email the forms as HTML. I assume you mean the data the user has entered. Have a look [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) Is a great and easy to user HTML to PDF converter. Maybe this helps getting you started.

Comment: yeah, sorry, should have made that clearer. The php form gets emailed to an email group based on the email template that is in html format.